# Login to Angular SPA with asp .net core 3 API without redirect outside of SPA

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have been looking into making an Angular SPA with dot net core 3 back end for API calls, I would like to secure the API and SPA with a login.

In all the examples I have found (such as the new core 3 Angular template, [and this](https://fullstackmark.com/post/21/user-authentication-and-identity-with-angular-aspnet-core-and-identityserver)) the code uses Identity Server. I have no problem with this EXCEPT for in every example the login process leaves the SPA for authentication/login and then redirects back to the SPA.

I don't want to leave the SPA. I want to do everything from inside the SPA as this to me is the best user experience. In the Microsoft template example you get redirected to a different page where the menu from the SPA is gone. If I were to do it this way I would have to maintain two separate menu systems.

So my question is, how do I do login with an Angular 7+, asp.net core 3, and not have any type of redirect away from the SPA. If I can't do this with Identity Server, then are there other options?

Update - I solved this by editing the SPA app and how the default identification process works so that I have a login form and a register form in the app. And then quietly do the call and redirect login to IS in the background without the user ever leaving the page.

Comment: It shouldn't be about user experience but about security. If you want to implement oidc (as IdentityServer does), you'll have to follow the specifications. This means that authentication is handled by the authority. Your client is not the authority in that case. As a result the client app(s) / api's remain ignorant of user's credentials this way, which is more secure than it is in your proposed setup. So the question is, do you want to implement oidc? Alternative is to use the resource owner password credentials flow, but that's not recommended because the client can then read the credentials

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I dont completly agree with you. Yes it needs to be about security, but you cant just throw user experience out the window either. Not if you want to keep your users comming back. I changed my app around so Im still using IS in the background, but im not using its forms for login and registration.

Comment: This is probably hypothetical, but how would you implement external providers, like google or facebook? Would you use your own forms in that case? Would you enter your credentials in a client that is in between of the provider?

Comment: For the purpose of this app there wont be external authentication. But if a user were to click on a button to authenticate with an external service, then I would also think they would expect to be bounced around a bit. I don't think they expect or want that when they are just trying to register a simple local-account in an app.

Comment: Which is fine when you have one app. Please note that with IdentityServer the user is not bound to one app. An authenticated user can access any client that uses the IdentityServer as provider.

Comment: I definitely understand that, and I understand why Microsoft did that as an example project, I just think in most cases this is not what is wanted for the people whom would use the example app as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Token). It is the ideal solution for SPA auth.

.NET Core Side:

- Create an API endpoint to provide JWT token. [IdentityServer issues access tokens in the JWT (JSON Web Token) format by default.](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html)
- Add [JWT Authorization Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to your web API project.
- Add `Authorize` attribute to APIs you want to protect.

Angular SPA Side:

- Call the newly created API with user provided credentials (ie. email and password) and store the token it provided.
- For every HTTP call to any protected API, the HTTP request need its Authorization Header supplied with the JWT token using the [Bearer schema](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement login/logout/etc in your SPA and use Identity Server.
Redirect from your SPA to your SPA by setting corresponding [urls](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#userinteraction) in options of `AddIdentityServer`.
Try replacing default pages from this [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/IdentityServer/Views/Account/Login.cshtml) one by one. You'll also have to modify [controllers](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs).